# Different brackets in pandas DataFrame.loc

Tags: pandas, dataframe

What is the difference in using `loc[x,y]` vs. `loc[x][y]` vs. `loc[[x]][y]`? They seem quite similar at first glance.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2),
                  columns=['price', 'count'],
                  index=['First', 'Second', 'Third'])
print(df)
#         price  count
# First       0      1
# Second      2      3
# Third       4      5

print(df.loc['Second', 'count'])
# 3

print(df.loc['Second']['count'])
# 3

print(df.loc[['Second'], 'count'])
# Second    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the first 2 are equivalent in output, the second is called chained indexing:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

the type also is a `Series` for the second one:

```
In[48]:
type(df.loc['Second'])

Out[48]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

you then index the index value which then returns the scalar value:

```
In[47]:
df.loc['Second']

Out[47]: 
price    2
count    3
Name: Second, dtype: int32

In[49]:
df.loc['Second']['count']

Out[49]: 3
```

Regarding the last one, the additional brackets returns a df which is why you see the index value rather than a scalar value:

```
In[44]:
type(df.loc[['Second']])

Out[44]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

So then passing the column, indexes this df and returns the matching column, as a `Series`:

```
In[46]:
type(df.loc[['Second'],'count'])

Out[46]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

So it depends on what you want to achieve, but avoid the second form as it can lead to unexpected behaviour when attempting to assign to the column or df

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent explanation! In the link you provided some operation are with `loc` and some are without it. Should we consider `dfmi['one']` to be any different from `dfmi.loc['one']`?

Comment: @Konstantin it depends on what you do next, if you did `dfmi['one']['Second']` then this would be chained indexing and it may return a copy or a view. If you just want to look at the data then either approach is fine, it's assignment is where problems can occur. In which case follow the recommendations in that link